# Match absolute tile sizes of two different ggplots when saving as PNG

Tags: r, ggplot2

When creating PNG files for a document using `ggplot2` and `geom_tile`, is there a way to set the size of the tiles to some absolute unit (cm, pt)? I have multiple plots that, when inserted into a document, do not have the exact same tile sizes. Of course I could change the width and height of the plots manually, so the tiles almost match each other, but that's cheating...

The variable names on the x- and y-axis have different lengths. So rather than setting the dimensions of the whole plot (including all the labels), I would like to set the dimensions of only the plot area to some fixed value, maybe through `scale_x/y_discrete`? Or maybe the individual plots can be extracted after they have been resized with `gridExtra` or `gtable`?

```
# Create some example data.
set.seed(1)
dt1 <- data.table(x=letters[1:5], y=rep(c("aaaaaaaaa", letters[2:3]), rep(5,3)),
                  value=runif(5*3))

dt2 <- data.table(x=letters[1:4], y=rep(letters[1:4], rep(4,4)),
                  value=runif(4*4))

# Make two tile plots.
p1 <- ggplot(dt1, aes(x, y, fill=value)) +
        geom_tile() +
        coord_equal(); p1

p2 <- ggplot(dt2, aes(x, y, fill=value)) +
        geom_tile() +
        coord_equal(); p2

# Save tile plots to drive.
# ggsave("p1.png", p1, width=5)
# ggsave("p2.png", p2, width=5)
```

Here's a screenshot from a document with PNG images inserted, note that the labels have the same size:

[image: Screenshot of document]

And this is what I'm after: the absolute distance between the red arrows is identical in both images, without resizing the labels.

[image: Edit with MS Paint...]

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's no ggplot-only solution AFAIK, but `set_panel_size` from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/baptiste/2877821) by @baptiste is probably what you're after. The only trouble is the grey margin since is it still inside the plotting area, so setting width(p1) to 5/4*width(p2) will result in an almost (but not exactly) equal tiles.